# Laravel save multiple images in database

Tags: laravel, image, eloquent

I am new in Laravel and I want to make a CRUD with cars and for every car to save multiple images in database.

My blade is :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('cars.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>
                    <label for="model" class="col-form-label">Model :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model">
                </legend>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="seats" class="col-form-label">Seats :</label>
                </legend>
                <select name="seats" id="seats">
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="fuel" class="col-form-label">Fuel :</label>
                </legend>
                <select name="fuel" id="fuel">
                    <option value="benzine+gpl">benzine+gpl</option>
                    <option value="gpl" selected="selected">diesel</option>
                    <option value="diesel">gpl</option>
                    <option value="diesel+gpl">diesel+gpl</option>
                    <option value="benzine">benzine</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="year" class="col-form-label">Year :</label>
                </legend>
                <input type="text" name="year" id="year">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>
                    <label for="color" class="col-form-label">Color :</label>
                </legend>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="gearbox" class="col-form-label">Gearbox :</label>
                </legend>
                <select name="gearbox" id="gearbox">
                    <option value="manual">manual</option>
                    <option value="automatic" selected="selected">automatic</option>
                    <option value="semiautomatic">semiautomatic</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="price" class="col-form-label">Price :</label>
                </legend>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="coinType" class="col-form-label">CoinType :</label>
                </legend>
                <select name="coinType" id="coinType">
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                    <option value="LEI" selected="selected">LEI</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <legend>
                    <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Upload images :</label>
                </legend>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" multiple />
            </div>


            <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add car</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('cars.index') }}"> Back</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

I have the first table named cars like this:

```
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('model');
        $table->integer('seats');
        $table->string('fuel');
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('gearbox');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('coinType');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and I have the second table with images like this:

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('car_id');
        $table->string('file_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'model' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'price'=> 'required',
        'file_name.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    $destionationPath = public_path('/images');
    $images = [];
  
    $car = new Car();
    $car->model = $request->model;
    $car->seats = $request->seats;
    $car->fuel = $request->fuel;
    $car->year = $request->year;
    $car->color = $request->color;
    $car->gearbox = $request->gearbox;
    $car->price = $request->price;
    $car->coinType = $request->coinType;
  

    $car->save();

    $image = new Image();
    if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destionationPath, $fileName);
            $images[] = $fileName;
        }
    }

    foreach ($images as $imag) {
        $image->car_id = $car->id;
        $image->file_name = json_encode($imag);
        $image->save();

    }
 
}
```

I have 2 Models: Cars and Image like this:

```
Car model:

   class Car extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'model',
        'seats',
        'fuel',
        'year',
        'color',
        'gearbox',
        'price',
        'coinType',
    ];

    public function images()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Image model:

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'car_id',
        'file_name'
    ];
    
    public function car()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}
```

If I select multiple photos, in my Image table i get just the last image . The othe pictures are overwritten. I put a dump in foreach and I get all the images from the View. But I think that i have a mistake when I save..I don't know how to save correctly.

Comment: I think the mistake was on your blade, if your input attribute  is `name=images` then change it to `name=images[]`

Comment: I have name = images[] in my blade

Comment: All images saved to your directory, but on database it saved the last one?

Comment: yes, all the images are saved in my directory but in database just the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every loop, you need to create a new model instance :

```
foreach ($images as $imag) {
     $image = new Image(); // new model instance
     $image->car_id = $car->id;
     $image->file_name = json_encode($imag);
     $image->save();
}
```